# PLY yacc parser lost first term after every newline

Tags: python, parsing, yacc, ply

I try to write a simple parser by PLY, but the parser below will lose the first string after every NEWLINE.

The input is "a b c\nb d e\nc f".

My parser parsed first line statement as state (0, ((('a', 'b'), 'c'), 0)), but next token 'b' is lost. The second line statement is state (0, (('d', 'e'), 0)). How do I fix this?

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

tokens = ('STRING', 'NEWLINE')
t_STRING  = r'[^ \n]+'
t_ignore = r' '

def t_NEWLINE(t):
    r'\n'
    t.lexer.lineno += 1
    return t

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character %s" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

def p_statement_interactive(p):
    '''statement : plist
                 | plist NEWLINE'''
    p[0] = (0, (p[1],0))
    print "state", p[0]

def p_item_string_expr(p):
    '''plist : plist pitem
             | pitem'''
    if len(p) > 2:
        p[0] = (p[1],p[2])
    else:
        p[0] = p[1]
    print "str2", p[0]

def p_item_string(p):
    '''pitem : STRING'''
    p[0] = p[1]
    print "str1", p[0]

def p_error(p):
    if not p:
        print("SYNTAX ERROR AT EOF")

def main():
    data = """a b c
    b d e
    c f"""

    lexer = lex.lex(debug=0)
    lexer.input(data)

    while True:
        tok = lexer.token()
        if not tok:
            break      # No more input
        print(tok)

    parser = yacc.yacc()
    parser.parse(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result is:

```
LexToken(STRING,'a',1,0)
LexToken(STRING,'b',1,2)
LexToken(STRING,'c',1,4)
LexToken(NEWLINE,'\n',1,5)
LexToken(STRING,'b',2,10)
LexToken(STRING,'d',2,12)
LexToken(STRING,'e',2,14)
LexToken(NEWLINE,'\n',2,15)
LexToken(STRING,'c',3,20)
LexToken(STRING,'f',3,22)
str1 a
str2 a
str1 b
str2 ('a', 'b')
str1 c
str2 (('a', 'b'), 'c')
state (0, ((('a', 'b'), 'c'), 0))
str1 d
str2 d
str1 e
str2 ('d', 'e')
state (0, (('d', 'e'), 0))
str1 f
str2 f
state (0, ('f', 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `p_error` function:

```
def p_error(p):
    if not p:
        print("SYNTAX ERROR AT EOF")
```

silently ignores errors except at the end of input. Silently ignoring errors is almost always wrong, and almost always confusing, as it is in this case.

Your `statement` production only accepts a single line, possibly terminated with a newline character. No token other than the end-of-file indicator can follow the newline. So the second token `b` -- that is, the token at the beginning of the second line -- causes a syntax error.

Since syntax errors are being silently ignored, there is no indication of this error. Since PLY will then enter error recovery mode, the parser will effectively restart. However, the offending token `b` has already been "handled", so the restart starts at the next token, `d`.

That will happen again after the second newline. Again, the `c` at the beginning of the third line will cause a syntax error, which is silently ignored, and then be discarded, and the parser will restart at input `f`.

It's not clear to me what your expectation is. One possibility would be to `raise SyntaxError` (or some other error type) in `p_error`, rather than just returning, to terminate the parse. However, the erroneous token will already have been discarded.

Or you might want to accept any number of statements. In that case, your statement rule should be something like

```
statement:
         | statement NEWLINE
         | statement NEWLINE plist
```

and the action associated with the third option would do whatever you needed done with the `plist`.